# Java replace issues with ' (apostrophe/single quote) and \ (backslash) together

Tags: java, string, replace, escaping, backslash

I seem to be having issues. I have a query string that has values that can contain single quotes. This will break the query string. So I was trying to do a replace to change `'` to `\'`.

Here is a sample code:

```
"This is' it".replace("'", "\'");
```

The output for this is still:

```
"This is' it".
```

It thinks I am just doing an escape character for the quote.

So I tried these two pieces of code:

```
"This is' it".replace("'", "\\'");  // \\ for the backslash, and a ' char
"This is' it".replace("'", "\\\'"); // \\ for the backslash, and \' for the ' char
```

Both of the above STILL results in the same output:

```
"This is' it"
```

I can only seem to get this to actually spit out a slash with:

```
"This is' it".replace("'", "\\\\'");
```

Which results in:

```
"This is\\' it"
```

Any suggestions? I just want to replace a `'` with `\'`.

It doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

Comment: Did you make a typo?  I don't see a difference between the last two code snippets, and the latter's results seem to be what you want.

Comment: "I have a query string" - did you mean a SQL query string? If so, use PreparedStatements and parameterized queries. Then you wouldn't have to deal with escaping these characters on your own.

Comment: I'm with jwodder on this.  What you want and what you get appear to be the same.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First of all, if you are trying to encode apostophes for querystrings, they need to be URLEncoded, not escaped with a leading backslash. For that use [`URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (BTW: the second argument should always be `"UTF-8"`). Secondly, if you want to replace all instances of apostophe with backslash apostrophe, you must escape the backslash in your string expression with a leading backslash. Like this:

```
"This is' it".replace("'", "\\'");
```

### Edit:

I see now that you are probably trying to dynamically build a SQL statement. **Do not** do it this way. Your code will be susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Instead use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: You are assuming he means HTTP query strings. He might. He might not.

Comment: @EJP: Yes. That's my assumption. I don't often hear the words "query string" in any other context. Let's wait and see if the OP clarifies otherwise.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, I am writing automation scripts that perform actions on a page.  A web page I am testing has a drop down with values from populated from the database.  So I grab the values from the database, randomly select one of the values from the result-set, and make the selection on the web page.  The problem I am having is that some of the values in the result-set contain single quotes.

Comment: @user770404: Are you building an http link or a SQL string?

Comment: Because one drop down selection drives another drop down value, to make the script versatile, I then use the random value selected previously and plug it into another query.  This causes problems if the previous value has a single quote as it terminates the query string I am passing.

Comment: @user770404: So this is SQL then? Yes? If so, you are going about this wrong. You should be using a `PreparedStatement`. Your current strategy is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: "select column_Name from table_name where column_name = '" + rndQueryValue + "'"  This is pretty much what I am doing.  So you can see that if rndQueryValue contains any quotes, this query string breaks.  So I was trying to do a replace on this rndQueryValue variable and replace ' with \'

Comment: I completely agree if this was an application.  As I mentioned, this is just a test script running locally to test a web application.

Comment: @user770404: I think I know what your issue is: You're putting the extra backslash in your HTML form. Don't do it there. Instead, do it when you construct the SQL. Like this: `"select column_Name from table_name where column_name = '" + rndQueryValue.replace("'", "\\'") + "'"`. But again, this is horrible. SQL Injection. Oy...

Comment: Hmm..I will give that a shot. I am using existing test framework, and upon closer look, the query string I build gets passed to a statement object. But SQL injection is not something that is a concern with this even if it was the case being that this is a test script grabbing values from our database to simulate users interacting with our application.

Comment: Thanks Asaph.  That seemed to work.  If I perform the replace at the time of passing the combined string/variable to the statement, then the query runs properly.

Comment: @derekmw: No problem. If you've found my answer helpful, please mark it correct by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `"This is' it".replace("'", "\\'")`

Comment: The apostrophe doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Escaping the `'` itself is not necessary here. Only the backslash must be escaped.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was hoping to use, but I that output becomes: "This is' it".  The slash does not get placed in the output for some reason.

Comment: @user770404 By output you mean you send it to System.Out?

Answer (score 4):

I have used a trick to handle the apostrophe special character. When replacing ' for \' you need to place four backslashes before the apostrophe.

```
str.replaceAll("'","\\\\'");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in JavaScript then you can use

```
str.replace("SP","\\SP");
```

But in Java

```
str.replaceAll("SP","\\SP");
```

will work perfectly.

SP: special character

Otherwise you can use Apache's EscapeUtil. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `stringToEdit.replaceAll(String, String)` *returns* the result string. It doesn't modify stringToEdit because Strings are immutable in Java. To get any change to stick, you should use

```
stringToEdit = stringToEdit.replaceAll("'", "\\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
String teste = " 'Bauru '";

teste = teste.replaceAll("  '  ","");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,teste);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used

```
str.replace("'", "");
```

to replace the single quote in my string. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Does this code actually remove the `'` from the string?