# How to get a string present within single quotes in a line using java

Tags: java, string

I have a line and from this line i want to get a string present between first single quotes
for example

This is a 'long' string to test and there are 'many' more to come to 'test'

and i need to get string value present between first single quotes i.e. **long** as a final result

Thanks

Comment: repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258270/java-replace-issues-with-apostrophe-single-quote-and-backslash-together

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question right I think what you want is to use split().

```
String a = "This is a 'long' string to test and there are 'many' more to come to 'test'";
    String[] b = a.split("'");
    System.out.println(b[1]);
```

b becomes an array of strings and the second element in the array will be the string between the first set of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

One Example of getting a substring

```
String str="This is a 'long' string to test and there are 'many' more to come to 'test'";
String tempStr=str.substring(str.indexOf('\'')+1);
String finalStr=tempStr.substring(0,tempStr.indexOf('\''));
System.out.println(finalStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using REGEX

```
    String test="This is a 'long' string to test"
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\'.*?\'");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test); 
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(test.substring(m.start()+1,test.end()-1));
    }
```