# Getting substring from a string that contains special char

Tags: java, string

I have a string

```
String exceptionMessage = "Duplicate entry 'Asd12345' for key 'UK_sb8bbouer5wak8vyiiy4pf2bx'"
```

I would like to extract `'Asd12345'` from the string. Can someone help with java string?

Expected output:

```
Asd12345
```

Comment: `exceptionMessage.substring(17, 25)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java regex content between single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746395/java-regex-content-between-single-quotes)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853049/how-to-get-a-string-present-within-single-quotes-in-a-line-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by getting the first `substring` between the single quotes:

```
String exceptionMessage = "Duplicate entry 'Asd12345' for key 'UK_sb8bbouer5wak8vyiiy4pf2bx'";
String subStr = exceptionMessage.substring(exceptionMessage.indexOf("'") + 1);
subStr = subStr.substring(0, subStr.indexOf("'"));
System.out.println(subStr);
```

The output here would be:

```
Asd12345
```

Answer (score -1):

with the string method replaceAll. there are many was to do it.
I suggest you te learn about regex it will help you to control strings.

```
String exceptionMessage = "Duplicate entry 'Asd12345' for key 'UK_sb8bbouer5wak8vyiiy4pf2bx'";
exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage.replaceAll("Asd12345", "");
```